# Getting "Connection "default" is not defined" during integration test sandbox setup

Tags: magento2.4.3, integration-test, continuous-integration

On a dockerized CI environment (Ubuntu 20.04) we are getting the following error:

```
cd dev/tests/integration; ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit -v --testsuite 'Our Tests'

...

Disabling Maintenance Mode:

In ResourceConnection.php line 148:

[DomainException]
Connection "default" is not defined
```

This seems during the automated sandbox installation.

When we run the command again, it works.

But after we deleted the sandboxes using

```
rm dev/tests/integration/tmp/sandbox-* -r
```

it does not work again on the first try.

We found https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22198 which says this could be related to the `opcache.enable_cli` option, but this one is already switched to `Off`.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

It did not happen for Magento 2.4.2 and surfaced after the upgrade to Magento 2.4.3.

EDIT: Exception trace:

```
Exception trace:
  at /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/ResourceConnection.php:148
 Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection->getConnectionByName() at /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/App/ResourceConnection.php:97
 Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection->getConnection() at /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Model/ResourceModel/Db/AbstractDb.php:333
 Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb->getConnection() at /var/www/vendor/magento/module-message-queue/Model/ResourceModel/Lock.php:103
 Magento\MessageQueue\Model\ResourceModel\Lock->releaseOutdatedLocks() at /var/www/vendor/magento/module-message-queue/Model/Plugin/ResourceModel/Lock.php:39
 Magento\MessageQueue\Model\Plugin\ResourceModel\Lock->afterSet() at /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:146
 Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() at /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153
 Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode\Interceptor->___callPlugins() at /var/www/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/MaintenanceMode/Interceptor.php:23
 Magento\Framework\App\MaintenanceMode\Interceptor->set() at /var/www/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:1442
 Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->setMaintenanceMode() at n/a:n/a
 call_user_func_array() at /var/www/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:389
 Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install() at /var/www/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/InstallCommand.php:231
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallCommand->execute() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:255
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1009
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:273
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:115
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:149
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/bin/magento:23
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is [issue #33802](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33802). A pull request linked there is reported to fix the issue.

Comment: I was facing an issue in setup:install and I found this patch from this PR it works for me thanks. @mam08ixo
https://github.com/magento/magento2/files/9569853/PR-33803-Framework.txt

apply this patch and issue is fixed

Answer (score 1):

Quick workaround: open your *app/etc/env.php* and duplicate the db.connection.default into a db.connection.db

Something like this:

```php
<?php

return [
    # [..]
    'db' => [
        # [..]
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => 'db',
                'dbname' => 'magento',
                'username' => 'magento',
                'password' => 'magento',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [
                    1014 => false
                ]
            ],
            'db' => [
                'host' => 'db',
                'dbname' => 'magento',
                'username' => 'magento',
                'password' => 'magento',
                'model' => 'mysql4',
                'engine' => 'innodb',
                'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
                'active' => '1',
                'driver_options' => [
                    1014 => false
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    # [..]
];
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is appearing again in 2.4.6-p2 and is tracked in [issue #37805](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/37805). At the time of wrinting this answer adobe is already working on this issue but no PR has been linked yet.

I have created a patch to get the integration tests running again until it is fixed properly:

```
@package magento/framework
@level 4

Index: vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php
IDEA additional info:
Subsystem: com.intellij.openapi.diff.impl.patch.CharsetEP
<+>UTF-8
===================================================================
diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php b/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php
--- a/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php
+++ b/vendor/magento/framework/App/DeploymentConfig.php (date 1692798116511)
@@ -94,9 +94,7 @@
         }
         $result = $this->getByKey($key);
         if ($result === null) {
-            if (empty($this->flatData) || count($this->getAllEnvOverrides())) {
-                $this->reloadData();
-            }
+            $this->reloadData();
             $result = $this->getByKey($key);
         }
         return $result ?? $defaultValue;
@@ -184,9 +182,7 @@
      */
     private function reloadInitialData(): void
     {
-        if (empty($this->readerLoad) || empty($this->data) || empty($this->flatData)) {
-            $this->readerLoad = $this->reader->load();
-        }
+        $this->readerLoad = $this->reader->load();
         $this->data = array_replace(
             $this->readerLoad,
             $this->overrideData ?? [],
```

Answer (score -3):

Replace hhvm with php7 and everything worked fine. The installer check needs to warn if hhvm is not supported

Comment: We are not using hhvm, but PHP7.4